# Rock band instrument compatibility

Tags: rock-band-3

We have the rock band 3 drum kit and guitar. 
Bought for the Xbox 360.  We got rid of the x box ages ago so my question is can the instruments be used on a PS3?  With the PS3 disc of course

Comment: I want to say no, since they're likely branded for Xbox 360, have the 360 buttons and system button, etc. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

From some quick Google searching, there are a few sources that come up with bad news:

Unfortunately, no, 360-branded Rockband instruments will not be compatible with a Playstation 3. This extends to the PS3 copy of Rockband. Furthermore, an adapter for this kind of deal does not exist either.

Sources [here](http://forums.harmonixmusic.com/discussion/44361/do-xbox-drums-work-on-a-ps3) and [here](http://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/949926-rock-band-2/answers/217377-can-you-use-ps3-drums-on-x-box) (to confirm the opposite direction as well).

Comment: Correct, they are not compatible.